# counting the number of values seperated by a set difference

Tags: r, database, data-science

I have a dataset of injury times from multiple datasources. I want to create two new columns indicating the number of seperate injuries a subject has sustained. One would be a binary Yes/No variable and one returning the number of injuries a subject has sustained.

The slight complicating factor is to be considered a seperate injury I want it to only count if there is more than 0.25 (years) separating the two recordings of the injury.

I have tried a few ways (see end) but not got a method that seems to work!

Below is an example dataset with an ID column and then 19 numeric columns which would be the time of injury columns.

**Example dataset**

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(42)

# Create the dataset
num_rows <- 50
num_cols <- 20

# Generate random IDs
ids <- sample(100000:999999, num_rows, replace = FALSE)

# Generate random numeric values between 4 and 80 with two decimal places
values <- matrix(runif(num_rows * num_cols, min = 4, max = 80), nrow = num_rows)

# Introduce NA values in each column (between 12 and 18 per row)
num_na <- sample(12:18, num_rows, replace = TRUE)
for (i in 1:num_rows) {
  na_indices <- sample(num_cols, num_na[i])
  values[i, na_indices] <- NA
}

# Ensure some rows only contain values within 0.25 of each other
for (i in 1:num_rows) {
  if (runif(1) < 0.2) {  # Adjust the probability as needed
    reference_value <- runif(1, min = 4, max = 80)
    values[i, ] <- round(runif(num_cols, min = reference_value - 0.125, max = reference_value + 0.125), 2)
  }
}

# Combine IDs and values into a data frame
data <- data.frame(id = ids, values)

# Print the first few rows of the generated dataset
head(data)
```

currently, the best I have got is the below:

```
data$Multiple_Injuries <- apply(data[, grepl("^X", colnames(data))], 1, function(x) {
  n_entries <- sum(!is.na(x))
  n_diff_gt_1 <- sum(diff(na.omit(x)) > 0.25)
  if (n_entries >= 2 && n_diff_gt_1 >= 1) {
    return("Yes")
  } else {
    return("No")
  }
})

#and

data$Number_of_injuries <- apply(data[, grepl("^X", colnames(data))], 1, function(x) {
  n_columns_with_entry <- sum(!is.na(x))
  diffs <- diff(na.omit(x))
  n_diffs_gt_quarter <- sum(diffs > 0.25)
  if (n_columns_with_entry > 1 && n_diffs_gt_quarter > 0) {
    return(n_columns_with_entry)
  } else {
    return(1)
  }
})
```

However, this is not picking up all the values/giving me the correct count (on visual inspection following).

Can anyone see an error? or suggest another solution that may answer the question?

Many thanks

Comment: Great question! Are the recordings (the "X" columns) in chronological order? ie, if X1 = 1.0, x2 = 10.0, and x3 = 1.01, what would you want the result to look like [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], or [1, 1, 1]? I could see a case for all three. Perhaps shorting your `data` to maybe 10 word and 5 columns and providing your desired output for those data would make this a bit easier. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, so in the original dataset they are not in chronological order. I simplified the dataset slightly for the reproducible example, the origional took injuries from seven sources, from each source they were ordered (_1, _2 and so on) for instance X_source1_1, X_source1_2, X_source2_1. This seemed a complexity that might confuse the issue a bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I've come up with:

```
data$Number_of_injuries <- apply(data[, grepl("^X", colnames(data))], 1, function(x) {
  return(((x %>% 
             as.numeric() %>% 
             sort %>% 
             diff) 
          > 0.25) %>% 
           sum + 
           any(!is.na(x)))
})

data$Multiple_Injuries <- data$Number_of_injuries > 1
```

Explanation:
`x` = input vector

`as.numeric()` -> this gets rid of all the NA values

`sort` -> sort the remaining numbers in ascending order

`diff` -> create difference between elements

`> 0.25` -> turn vector containing differences into logical vector indicating whether the difference is greater than 0.25 or not

`sum` -> sum of the logical vector gives the count of injuries where the difference to the last injury is greater than 0.25

`any(!is.na(x))` -> adds one to the injury count if there is data in the row (to account for the first injury), or 0 if there are no injuries recorded

Comparison to your solution:

```
> data[,!grepl("^X", colnames(data))]
       id Number_of_injuries Multiple_Injuries Multiple_Injuries_old Number_of_injuries_old
1  161412                  3              TRUE                   Yes                      3
2  154424                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
3  723843                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
4  174361                  7              TRUE                   Yes                      7
5  146207                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
6  509955                  6              TRUE                   Yes                      7
7  685892                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
8  959667                  8              TRUE                   Yes                      8
9  726545                  2             FALSE                    No                      1
10 686328                  3              TRUE                    No                      1
11 789059                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
12 421502                  5              TRUE                   Yes                      5
13 941220                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
14 349761                  7              TRUE                   Yes                      7
15 865799                  3              TRUE                   Yes                      3
16 285657                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
17 113609                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
18 598845                  6              TRUE                   Yes                      6
19 783918                  5              TRUE                   Yes                      5
20 491481                  5              TRUE                   Yes                      6
21 621507                  6              TRUE                   Yes                      6
22 338549                  8              TRUE                   Yes                      8
23 206092                  2             FALSE                    No                      1
24 843620                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
25 348033                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
26 607825                  3              TRUE                    No                      1
27 242295                  5              TRUE                   Yes                      5
28 526928                  2             FALSE                   Yes                      2
29 426553                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      5
30 202661                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
31 440097                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
32 350882                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
33 443444                  8              TRUE                   Yes                      8
34 174742                  7              TRUE                   Yes                      7
35 459097                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
36 736967                  6              TRUE                   Yes                      6
37 386752                  7              TRUE                   Yes                      8
38 100102                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
39 306956                  8              TRUE                   Yes                      8
40 732136                  8              TRUE                   Yes                      8
41 923371                  7              TRUE                   Yes                      7
42 302504                  6              TRUE                   Yes                      6
43 775362                  3              TRUE                   Yes                      3
44 886447                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
45 423291                  1             FALSE                    No                      1
46 606861                  3              TRUE                    No                      1
47 395899                  4              TRUE                   Yes                      4
48 468257                  8              TRUE                   Yes                      8
49 179767                  2             FALSE                   Yes                      2
50 125489                  6              TRUE                   Yes                      6
```